# -bash: ./run.dev.sh: /bin/bash^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory

Tags: linux, windows, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am trying to compile an api on my ubuntu console on windows 10.

I downloaded a repo of people who work with mac, and when I hit run.dev.sh I get the following error

> -bash: ./run.dev.sh: /bin/bash^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory

Try the dos2unix format, it doesn't work either.

Comment: "Try the dos2unix format, it doesn't work either." Does it mean it failed to change line endings or that it did successfully, but you still get `^M` reported?

Comment: With the dos2unix command it gives the same answer that I just put below @ÁlvaroGonzález

Comment: Verify what line ending you're using. If your editor doesn't display that information, upload it to [hexed.it](https://hexed.it/). If you happen to be using Git on Windows, unfortunately the default is to convert line endings to Windows style. But diagnose the problem first.

Comment: I don't understand what information you need... I don't know what a line ending is haha
I put the file in hexed.it but I don't know what to send you

#!/bin/bash
This?

Comment: Unix uses LF (hexadecimal `0a` in ASCII and UTF-8). Windows uses CRLF (hexadecimal `0d0a` in ASCII and UTF-8). On a side note, I really recommend you find a text editor that handles this natively.

Comment: I use vscode as editor. Sorry I can't give you more specific information, I really have zero knowledge on this topic.

Comment: You're unable to read the screen in hexedit and see if you have 0a or 0d0a? But if you use Code you have the information right in the status bar, either "LF" or "CRLF". Click on it to change it. Bash scripts won't work with CRLF. `dos2unix` should have fixed that, if used correctly.

Comment: Oh well, yes. Here I found, it is in CRLF. If I execute the run with this config, it throws the usual error.

If I change to LF and run again, it throws the image error (they deleted it, I'll upload it again)

I think dos2unix changes the format to LF, right? Same mistake.

(I don't know if it will be relevant information, but first of all it won't let me start it due to lack of permissions, so I have to do chmod +x ./run.dev.sh)

Comment: sed -i -e 's/\r$//' run.dev.sh | change to LF | or dos2unix, all throws the image error

https://i.stack.imgur.com/IdNxE.png

Comment: To confirm you're not editing one version of the file, but the system is running another, change the first line to `#!/bin/sh` and add an `echo "HERE WE ARE"` or similar on the next line. Also, consider having someone else that is a computer savy look at your problem (without too much explaining from you). A 2nd set of eyes often solve such problems. Good luck.